# Ionic framework ion-scroll pinch to zoom on iOS causes blurred images.

Tags: ios, angularjs, image, ionic-framework, blur

I have setup an ion-scroll tag with a background image, when running on iOS it appears to take a snapshot of it zoomed out and scroll that which results in blurred images.

I have tried swapping PNG for SVG but the same issue happens.

I have looked on the official forum and there seems to be no answer yet, so I wondered if there was a CSS rule I could use or whether there was an alternative angularjs directive I could use.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue while trying to display an image in an Ionic v1 ion-scroll container and was able to address it. I posted my results on StackOverflow:

[Ion-scroll blurs my image when zooming in in ionic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017052/ion-scroll-blurs-my-image-when-zooming-in-in-ionic-framework)